# CSS3/JS get position of element during animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to get position of element like (with jQuery)

```
$(".mydiv").position().left;
```

However I need to do it during `css3 translate animation`. This animation translate of div position is included in `position()` data.

**Is it possible to get position of element during animation, but position without any translations (just like there would be no animation)?**

Comment: why not save it in a var, a moment before you start the transition?

Comment: It's becouse when element has some css animation it starts to play instantly when item is added to DOM, and I can mensure anything AFTER item is added to DOM, so there is no way I can do it 'before' it is animated.

Comment: if you are adding the animation manually, then save the position before adding the animation. if the animation is set in css and starts playing as soon as dom loads, then the position is the same one you set in css, or can be calculated if you change it using javascript

Comment: I think it's only in case first keyframe of animation has no translation. But for example when you have animation like "fade-in-from-left" (that is my case) with translation of 100px to side on the start of animation, this is added to position and its not round number.

Comment: ok let me understand, your animation is hardcoded in the css file yes?, i meant, you dont attach the animation using javascript, it is hardcoded in your css file to start as soon as css loads yes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit

> "I'm not using .animate for simple animations since css3. –  Kluska000"

Should still be able to utilize jquery's `animate()` `start`, `step`, `progress` callback functions - even though actual animation done at `css`. e.g., could utilize `.animate()` at target element - without actually animating the element - only to utilize `start`, `step`, `progress` callback functions; with `duration` synced to `css` animations duration . Also, appear that jquery `.animate()` does not actually require that a target be a `DOM` element; could be 2 js `objects`.

See also `window.requestAnimationFrame()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/

Try (see `console` at jsfiddle, linked below)

```
  $(function() {
    $(".mydiv").animate({
      left :"0px"
      }, {
      duration : 1234,
      start : function (promise) {
              console.log($(".mydiv").position().left);
      },
      step : function (now, tween) {
              console.log($(".mydiv").position().left); 
      },
      progress : function (promise) {
              console.log($(".mydiv").position().left); 
      },
      complete : function () {
              $(this).animate({left:"0px"}, 1234)
      }
    });  
  });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/xwL7v/

See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ at `start` , `step` , `progress`

Comment: I'm not using .animate for simple animations since css3.

Answer (score 3):

well, regardless of how you create your animation, i think the best way would be to create an animation class and attach it as soon as dom loads, but only after recording the position for later use.

basically it would give you the same effect as if you set the animation right away, but you will have a record of all the details for later use:

Live Demo:  <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/ZteKp/)**</kbd>

ps: i made the demo for chrome, just change/remove the -webkit- for other browsers as needed:

```
-webkit-: chrome, safari
-moz-: firefox
-ms- : internet explorer
-o-: opera
without prefix: default
```

html:

```
<div id="status_div">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="slider"></div>
```

css:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#slider {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    display:block;
    background:red;
}
.SliderAnim {
    -webkit-animation:some_animation 2000ms linear forwards;
}
#status_div {
    position:relative;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    border:2px solid navy;
    color:black;
}
@-webkit-keyframes some_animation {
    from {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(-100px);
    }
    to {
        -webkit-transform:translateX(100px);
    }
}
```

js:

```
$(function () {
    // those are the position and offset before animation was attached
    var pX = $("#slider").position().left;
    var pY = $("#slider").position().top;
    var oX = $("#slider").offset().left;
    var oY = $("#slider").offset().top;
    // those are declarations for vars which will store the position and offset
    // of the element right after attaching the animation, and will result in the values
    // of the first fram of the animation
    var npX = 0;
    var npY = 0;
    var noX = 0;
    var noY = 0;
    // this is a timer function to write the details on the status bar
    setInterval(function () {
        // those are the position and offset of the element during the animation
        var apX = $("#slider").position().left;
        var apY = $("#slider").position().top;
        var aoX = $("#slider").offset().left;
        var aoY = $("#slider").offset().top;
        //print status bar info
        $("#status_div").html("BEFORE ATTACHING ANIMATION position: " + pX + "," + pY + "  offset: " + oX + "," + oY + " <br/> AFTER ATTACHING ANIMATION position: " + npX + "," + npY + "  offset: " + noX + "," + noY + "<br/> DURING ANIMATION position: " + apX + "," + apY + "  offset: " + aoX + "," + aoY);
    }, 100);
    //attach the animation class to the slider div 
    $("#slider").addClass("SliderAnim");
    //record the changed (will result in the first animation frame)
    npX = $("#slider").position().left;
    npY = $("#slider").position().top;
    noX = $("#slider").offset().left;
    noY = $("#slider").offset().top;
});
```