# Keeping seperate track of id attributes in a .animate's step function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a series of blocks that fall, and when they get to a certain point a grey block (placeholder for dust) appears; it goes away if the block bounces up past a certain point, then reappears when the block falls down again, getting smaller each time impact occurs.

Currently, however, since a *class* for the grey block is what is being affected, any falling block affects the overall size of the "dust" block despite falling and hitting at different times. I would like to keep track of each dust block separately, so each one changes depending on when the color block it is associated with impacts on the ground.

I've tried using ids - id='smoke"+i+"', $("#smoke"+i).height(40+smokeGlobal); - instead of a single class, but it appears doing that only allows the first block to animate. (I assumed a "for" loop is necessary there, but adding that in seemed to cancel the dust block altogether.)

As always, help would be appreciated. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/pjhoL899/1/

**JS:**

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#hamumu", "#beep", "#jk"];
var linkGlobal;
smokeGlobal = 0;

//home page functions
$(document).ready(function homePage() {

    //check collisions
    //initial animation
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        //animate links
        $(links[i]).animate({
            top: '0'
        }, { 
            duration: 2000*(Math.random()*(2)+1), 
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            step: function(y) {
                if (y >= -2) {
                    smokeGlobal -= 2;
                    linkGlobal = $(this);
                    linkGlobal.html("<div class='smoke' id='smoke"+i+"'></div>");
                    $(".smoke").height(40+smokeGlobal);
                    $(".smoke").fadeTo("fast", 0);
                }

            }, complete: setTimeout(function() {
                   linkGlobal.html("");
            }, 2000)
        });
    } 
})
```

Comment: `step` ordinarily accept `now, tween` as parameters; should be able to find element and properties within `tween` object; track position of property with `now` . There is also a `progress` callback which could be utilized, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555612/css3-js-get-position-of-element-during-animation/24556222#24556222

Comment: If you have time could you give me an example on JSFiddle, or perhaps edit the fiddle I provided? http://jsfiddle.net/pjhoL899/1/

Comment: Ah, cheers & thanks, mate! I'm going to bed soon but will definitely try this out tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Edit, updated

Substituted `now` for `y` and `$(tween.elem)` for `$(this)` at `step` function. `step` function argument `tween` is one of objects within jquery [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) ; having several properties , including currently animated element (`elem`) ; `easing` ; `now` ; `options` - which also has `queue` property (see [.queue()](http://api.jquery.com/queue/)).

For each element within the set `links` , the currently animated property could be retrieved utilizing `tween` object , along with the elements' animated position between the `start` and `end` of the animated property.

At original post , `y` could actually be utilized as `now` argument ; and `$(this)` for `linkGlobal` . The `tween` object should give access to the animated element at the specific portion of the animation required ; for adjustment of the element , animation , callback.

To keep track of each dust block separately , can access that element through `.fadeTo()` callback , or utilize `done` callback to adjust effects ; `done` fires before `complete` . `done` also has `promise` which could be utilized to adjust next animated element . There may be several potential options available to adjust features utilizing `.animate()`.

Try (this pattern)

```
var links = ["#portfolio", "#hamumu", "#beep", "#jk"];
var linkGlobal;
smokeGlobal = 0;

//home page functions
$(document).ready(function homePage() {

    //check collisions
    //initial animation
    for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
        //animate links
        $(links[i]).animate({
            top: '0'
        }, { 
            duration: 2000*(Math.random()*(2)+1), 
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            step: function(now, tween) {
                console.log(now, tween);
                // substituted `now` for `y`
                if (now >= -2) {
                    smokeGlobal -= 2;
                    // substituted `$(tween.elem)` for `$(this)`
                    linkGlobal = $(tween.elem);
                    linkGlobal.html("<div class='smoke' id='smoke"+i+"'></div>");

                    // adjust "dust" colors , 
                    // from checking `tween.elem` `backgroundColor` , `now`
                    var color = linkGlobal.css("background-color");
                    $(".smoke").eq(0)
                    .css("background-color"
                    , color === "yellow" && now < -1.05 ? "purple" : "orange");
                    $(".smoke").eq(1)
                    .css("background-color"
                    , color === "purple" && now < -0.00025 ? "orange" : "pink");
                    $(".smoke").eq(2)
                    .css("background-color"
                    , color === "pink" && now >= -0.0075 ? "purple" : "yellow");
                    $(".smoke").eq(3)
                    .css("background-color"
                    , color === "orange" && now < -0.003 ? "pink" : "purple");
                    // alert(now);

                    $(".smoke").height(40+smokeGlobal);
                    $(".smoke").fadeTo("fast", 0);
                }

            }, complete: setTimeout(function() {
                   linkGlobal.html("");
            }, 2000)
        });
    } 
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/pjhoL899/10/

Comment: The OP and other future visitors will probably be thankful if you **explained** your solution.