# Detection of collision or touching of html elements using angular 4

Tags: css, angular, typescript, animation

I am currently stuck at a point. i am using css animations to move p elements inside div from left to right at different speed. I want them to change their direction once they touch each other? How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There was a new browser API introduced for this recently that might do what you want

[Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API)

otherwise you might need to calculate that yourself using methods explained in [How to check if an element is overlapping other elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066870/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-overlapping-other-elements) or https://gist.github.com/jtsternberg/c272d7de5b967cec2d3d
by getting position and size of elements and compare them.

Comment: I can do that but I need some event to fire to get the position information of each element.? How to fire that event? How can I get continuous information about say left property of the element?

Comment: Right. I don't know how that works with CSS animations. Using `window.requestAnimationFrame()` might do it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24555612/css3-js-get-position-of-element-during-animation. Perhaps it's easier with web animatons? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API.